# nginx would not react to wildcard subdomains (*.domain)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx, dns

i have have trouble with nginx wildcard sub-domains.

I've bought a domain from godaddy. then create host zone in amazone and then created a record set for A(A-IPv4) - for both www.domain.com / domain.com

and in nginx.conf i have the very basic configuration and 1 server file that look like this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;


    access_log   /var/log/nginx/domain.com.access.log;
    error_log    /var/log/nginx/domain.com.error.log;

    # i tried the following for server name: domain.com *.domain.com/*.domain.com/.domain.com
    server_name .domain.com;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/test;
    index index.html;
```

}

when i visit subdomain.domain.com i get Firefox can't find the server at subdomain.domain.com

looking at the access log files nothing got logged it's completely empty.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add A-record for subdomains too. And before visiting site in Firefox, try ping - you will see if domain name can be resolved at all.

Comment: what you mean add an a-record for subdomains ?

Comment: http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/4080/managing-a-domain-names-subdomains - Adding a Subdomain section

Comment: i think i am going to have add subdomain to amazone rout 53 not in godaddy

Comment: where did you add www.domain.com / domain.com ?

Comment: I bought the domain from godaddy, then in amazon i've create the nameserver by adding a new host zone, and in there i've added an a record to my ec2 instance's public ip. then i added those 4 NS to godaddy DN manager

Comment: well thanks for directing me to the right direction i will ask another question on how to setup a wildcard subdomain for rout53 -> godaddy.